# I want to extract IMDb movie IDs using python

Tags: python, data-science

Here is my code:
So I wanted to extract all the bollywood movies, and the project requires, movie titles, cast, crew, IMDB id etc.... I am not able to get all the IMDb IDs with the error nonetype. When I used it on one page only it was working quite well, however, when I use it on multiple pages it shows an error. Please help

```
#importing the libraries needed 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint

#declaring the list of empty variables, So that we can append the data overall

movie_name = []
year = []
time=[]
rating=[]
votes = []
description = []
director_s = []
starList= []
imdb_id = []

#the whole core of the script
url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&primary_language=hi&sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&ref_=adv_nxt"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
movie_data = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})

for store in movie_data:
    name = store.h3.a.text
    movie_name.append(name)
    
    year_of_release = store.h3.find('span', class_ = "lister-item-year text-muted unbold").text
    year.append(year_of_release)
        
    runtime = store.p.find("span", class_ = 'runtime').text if store.p.find("span", class_ = 'runtime') else " "
    time.append(runtime)
        
    rate = store.find('div', class_ = "inline-block ratings-imdb-rating").text.replace('\n', '') if store.find('div', class_ = "inline-block ratings-imdb-rating") else " "
    rating.append(rate)
        
    value = store.find_all('span', attrs = {'name': "nv"})
        
    vote = value[0].text if store.find_all('span', attrs = {'name': "nv"}) else " "
    votes.append(vote)
        
    # Description of the Movies 
    describe = store.find_all('p', class_ = 'text-muted')
    description_ = describe[1].text.replace('\n', '') if len(describe) > 1 else ' '
    description.append(description_)
        
    ## Director  
    ps = store.find_all('p')
    for p in ps:
        if 'Director'in p.text:
            director =p.find('a').text
    
    director_s.append(director)
    
    ## ID
    imdbID = store.find('span','rating-cancel').a['href'].split('/')[2]
    imdb_id.append(imdbID)

    ## actors
    star = store.find("p", attrs={"class":""}).text.replace("Stars:", "").replace("\n", "").replace("Director:", "").strip()
    starList.append(star)


Error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17576/2711511120.py in <module>
     63 
     64         ## IDs
---> 65         imdbID = store.find('span','rating-cancel').a['href'].split('/')[2] if store.find('span','rating-cancel').a['href'].split('/')[2] else ' '
     66         imdb_id.append(imdbID)
     67 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: I ran your example code and got no errors. Is this the code you are running on one page or multiple pages?

Comment: Oh really, I was trying but getting 'none' type error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition to the following, cause first you have to check if `<span>` exists:

```
imdbID = store.find('span','rating-cancel').a.get('href').split('/')[2] if store.find('span','rating-cancel') else ' '
```

###### Example

Check the url, here are some of the `<span>` missing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#the whole core of the script
url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&primary_language=hi&sort=my_ratings,desc"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
movie_data = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})

for store in movie_data:
    imdbID = store.find('span','rating-cancel').a.get('href').split('/')[2] if store.find('span','rating-cancel') else ' '
    print(imdbID)
```

##### Output

```
tt9900050
tt9896506
tt9861220
tt9810436
tt9766310
tt9766294
tt9725058
 
tt9700334
 
tt9680166
 
tt9602804
```

---

Even better scrape the id via image tag cause these is always there even if there is only the placholder:

```
imdbID = store.img.get('data-tconst')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, its working now. I will credit you in my work. Thanks